# Intuition behind redundant information

Tags: multivariate-analysis, information-theory, mutual-information, multivariate-distribution

Suppose we have a set of variables, we call them "sources" ${\bf S} = \{S_1,\ldots,S_n\}$, and a "target" variable, denoted with $Y$. A measure of overall dependency between ${\bf S}$ and $Y$ is the joint mutual information
$$I(\{S_1,\ldots,S_n\};Y)$$
In information theory, it is often necessary to define a measure of *redundant information* of the set ${\bf S}$  about the target $Y$: from what I understood, redundancy is the *same* information that can be found in any of the sources $S_i$.

For example, for just 2 sources, the fact that
$$I(S_1,S_2;Y) < I(S_1;Y) + I(S_2;Y)$$
denotes the fact that at least some information is shared between $S_1$ and $S_2$.

Now I found some different definitions of this concept, the one that I am using is

$$\mathcal{R}(\{S_1,\ldots,S_n\};Y) \equiv \sum_{y} p(y) \min_{S_i}{I(Y=y;S_i)}~,$$
where $I(Y=y;S_i)$ is the so-called *specific information* and represents how much information $S_i$ provides about each particular outcome $y$:
$$I(Y=y;S) = \sum_{s}p(s|y) \log{\frac{p(s|y)}{p(s)}}.$$

For me this definition does not make much sense. Why the minimum of information that any source provides is *also* the information common to all sources? I know that many other definition exists, but this is (from what I know) one of the most used [introduced in this classic paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.2515).
Any experts of information theory that help me to understand or at least to build some intuition?